# Create subplot, for every group/id of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

I have the below dataframe:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create dataset
data = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,
               4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,],
        'cycle': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,],
        'Salary': [6, 7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   3, 4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   2, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
                   1, 8,9,10,11,12,],
        'Children': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes','Yes',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','Yes',],
        'Days': [141, 123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 141, 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 141,  15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,
                 141, 141,123, 128, 66,67,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("\n df = \n",df)
```

Now, here I wish to plot the `cycle` vs `Salary`, for all `id`'s of the dataframe in one single plot. Thus I need to use subplot function as such:

```
## Plot for all id's
plt_fig_verify = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

## id1: 
plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(df.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle'], df.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id1')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

## id2: 
plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(df.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle'], df.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id2')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

## id3: 
plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(df.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle'], df.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id3')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

## id4: 
plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.plot(df.groupby(by="id").get_group(4)['cycle'], df.groupby(by="id").get_group(4)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id4')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

However, here I need to write the codes for the subplot function four times, i.e. for all four id's of the dataframe.

Is there any way out, by which we can have some iterative function and write the subplot function only once and get all four subplots.

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in `Python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is a *for-loop* to [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html) each `group` of ids :

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))

for n, g in df.groupby("id"):
    g.plot(
        x="cycle", y="Salary",
        xlabel="Cycle", ylabel="Salary",
        label=f"id {n}",
        ax=ax,
)

plt.show();
```

[image]

Or, if you need to create a subplot for each id, you can use :

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8), nrows=2, ncols=2)

for (n, g), ax in zip(df.groupby("id"), axs.flatten()):
    g.plot(
        x="cycle", y="Salary",
        xlabel="Cycle", ylabel="Salary",
        label=f"id {n}",
        ax=ax,
    )

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timeless for your valuable suggestions. Also, is there any way out by which we can create the subplots?

Comment: You're welcome, I updated the answer to include that as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timeless for your valuable feedback. I have a similar doubt wherein I need to overlap for two different datafrmes. I have opened a question here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76499877/create-subplot-by-overlapping-two-different-dataframes-for-every-group-id-in   Could you please help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

- With data in a long-form, as this is, the easiest option is to use `seaborn`

  - `pandas.DataFrame.plot` uses `matplotlib` as the default backend, and `seaborn` is a high-level API for `matplotlib`.
  - If the data is in a wide-form, the easiest option is usually `pandas.DataFrame.plot`
  - Use the best `matplotlib` API for the shape of the dataframe.
- See [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)

  - [`sns.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html) is an axes-level function
  - [`sns.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) is a figure-level function

```py
import seaborn as sns

# use hue='id' for a single plot
ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x="cycle", y="Salary", hue='id', legend='full', palette='tab10')
```

[image]

```py
# se col='id' for subplots
g = sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df, x="cycle", y="Salary", col='id', col_wrap=2, height=3)
```

[image]