# Create subplot, by overlapping two dataframes, for every group/id

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, group-by

I have the below two dataframe:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create dataset_1
data_set_1 = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,
               4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,],
        'cycle': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,],
        'Salary': [6, 7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   3, 4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   2, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
                   1, 8,9,10,11,12,],
        'Children': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes','Yes',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','Yes',],
        'Days': [141, 123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 141, 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 141,  15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,
                 141, 141,123, 128, 66,67,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe_1
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_set_1)
print("\n df_1 = \n",df_1)



#Create dataset_2
data_set_2 = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,
               4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,],
        'cycle': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,],
        'Salary': [7, 8, 8, 8,8,9,14,21,12,19,14,20,
                   1, 6, 3, 8,4,9,8,
                   6, 4,9,10,4,12,13,6,
                   1, 4,9,10,9,4,],
        'Children': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes','Yes',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','Yes',],
        'Days': [141, 123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 141, 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 141,  15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,
                 141, 141,123, 128, 66,67,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe_2
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_set_2)
print("\n df_2 = \n",df_2)
```

Now, here I wish to plot the `cycle` vs `Salary`, and overlap for two dataframes for every `id`, in one single plot. Thus I need to use subplot function as such:

```
## Plot for all id's
plt_fig_verify = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

## id1: 
plt.subplot(4,1,1)
plt.plot(df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle'], df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id1: df_1')
plt.plot(df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle'], df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Salary'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='id1: df_2')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

## id2: 
plt.subplot(4,1,2)
plt.plot(df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle'], df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id2: df_1')
plt.plot(df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle'], df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Salary'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='id2: df_2')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

## id3: 
plt.subplot(4,1,3)
plt.plot(df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle'], df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id3: df_1')
plt.plot(df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle'], df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Salary'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='id3: df_2')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

## id4: 
plt.subplot(4,1,4)
plt.plot(df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(4)['cycle'], df_1.groupby(by="id").get_group(4)['Salary'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='id4: df_1')
plt.plot(df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(4)['cycle'], df_2.groupby(by="id").get_group(4)['Salary'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='id4: df_2')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('Salary')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

The result looks as such:

[image]

However, here I need to write the codes for the subplot function four times, i.e. for all four id's of the dataframe, and then overlap.

Is there any way out, by which we can have some iterative function and write the subplot function only once and get all four overalapped subplots.

Can somebody please let me know how to achieve this task in `Python`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the two dataframes, then use a single `groupby` to make the subplots :

```
colors = {"df_1": "blue", "df_2": "red"}
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], keys=colors)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8), nrows=2, ncols=2)

for (n, g), ax in zip(df.groupby("id"), axs.flatten()):
    for s in df.index.levels[0]:
        g.loc[s].plot(
            x="cycle", y="Salary",
            xlabel="Cycle", ylabel="Salary",
            label=f"id {n}: {s}",
            color=colors[s],
            ax=ax
        )

plt.tight_layout()

plt.show();
```

Output :

[image]

If you need a single col, you can update the `subplots` configuration this way :

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8), nrows=len(df["id"].unique()))
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. I added an option you can have a single column and multiple rows. Happy coding ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Timeless for your valuable feedback! I have another scenario wherein the two dataframes have different shapes and column names. I have opened a discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76500170/create-subplot-by-overlapping-two-different-dataframes-of-diffrent-shapes-and-c Could you please let me know how do we create overlapped subplots in this situtaion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want these plots as subplots with a short, clean, and interactive code I advise you to use Plotly!
you just need to execute `pip install plotly`, and the nice thing about it is that pandas allow you to use plotly as a backend engine for plotting!
after importing pandas `import pandas as pd`, you write this small piece of code `pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"`. and that's all! you can use Plotly!

I merged the two DataFrames you created; I created a column called `source` to differentiate between the input of the first DataFrame and the input of the second one.
Here is the modified code sample:

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = "plotly"

#Create dataset_1
data_set_1 = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,
               4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,],
        'cycle': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,],
        'Salary': [6, 7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,
                   3, 4, 4, 4,4,5,6,
                   2, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,
                   1, 8,9,10,11,12,],
        'Children': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes','Yes',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','Yes',],
        'Days': [141, 123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 141, 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 141,  15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,
                 141, 141,123, 128, 66,67,],
        }

#Create dataset_2
data_set_2 = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,
               4, 4, 4, 4, 4,4,],
        'cycle': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,],
        'Salary': [7, 8, 8, 8,8,9,14,21,12,19,14,20,
                   1, 6, 3, 8,4,9,8,
                   6, 4,9,10,4,12,13,6,
                   1, 4,9,10,9,4,],
        'Children': ['Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'No', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'Yes', 
                     'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes', 'No','No', 'Yes','Yes',
                     'Yes', 'Yes', 'No','Yes', 'Yes','Yes',],
        'Days': [141, 123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 141, 96, 120,120, 141, 52,96,
                 141,  15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,
                 141, 141,123, 128, 66,67,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe_1
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data_set_1).assign(source='df_1')

#Convert to dataframe_2
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data_set_2).assign(source='df_2')

fig = (
    pd.concat([df_1, df_2])
    .plot.line(x='cycle', y='Salary', color='source', title='Salary by cycle', facet_row='id', markers=True)
)
fig.show()
```

You should get interactive subplots like in the image below:
[image: Interactive subplots between Salary and Cycle]

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @AliMassoud for your valuable suggestions! I tried to implement your codes as it is. However, the plot dosent show up. Is the python version causing any problem? I am using Python 3.7.6. Please let me know your suggestions

Comment: I don't think it is a python version issue, are you running the code on a notebook?
if so, can you check if you have ipywidgets? pip install ipywidgets.  
https://pypi.org/project/plotly/
here is a link to double-check if you have the requirements.

Comment: I am using IDLE editor for python codes. I dont see any error message popping up. Its just that the plot doesnt appear. Could you please let me know your views. Shall I use jupyter? Will this code not work in IDLE ?

Comment: yes, it makes sense, since you are using a script you need to store the figure and then show it, I updated the code accordingly, this way it should work on both IDLE and a notebook. I like Plotly because it is interactive. I hope it will work now and play with the plotting and you will get exactly why it is powerful.
I hope it will help. let me know if further help is needed.