# Create subplot of multiple columns, by overlapping two dataframes of different shapes and column names, for every group/id

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, group-by, subplot

I have the below two datasets with different shapes and column/feature names.

```
#Load the required libraries
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Create dataset_1
data_set_A = {'id': [1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,],
        'cycle_1': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,],
        'Salary_1': [6, 7, 7, 7,8,9,10,11,12,
                   3, 4, 4, 4,
                   2, 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,],
        'Children_1': [1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0,2, 1,
                     0, 1, 1, 2,  
                     1, 2,0, 1, 2,0, 1,0,],
        'Expenditure_1': [141, 123, 128, 66, 66, 120, 141, 52, 52,
                 141, 96, 120,120, 
                 141,  15,123, 128, 66, 120, 141, 141,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe_1
data_A = pd.DataFrame(data_set_A)
print("\n data_A = \n",data_A)



#Create dataset_2
data_set_B = {'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
               3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3,],
        'cycle_2': [0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2.0,2.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6,0.8,1.0,1.2,
                  0.0, 0.2,0.4, 0.6, 0.8,1.0,1.2,1.4,],
        'Salary_2': [7, 8, 8, 8,8,9,14,21,12,19,14,20,
                   1, 6, 3, 8,4,9,8,
                   6, 4,9,10,4,12,13,6,],
        'Children_2': [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2,2, 0, 1, 0, 2,
                     1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
                     1, 2,1, 0, 2,0, 1,0,],
        'Expenditure_2': [79, 82, 128, 66, 42, 120, 141, 52,96, 120, 141, 52,
                 30, 96, 86,120, 91, 52,96,
                 28,  15,51, 128, 76, 120, 87, 141,],
        }

#Convert to dataframe_2
data_B = pd.DataFrame(data_set_B)
print("\n data_B = \n",data_B)
```

The features are: 'Salary', 'Children', and 'Expenditure'.

**NOTE:** 'id' and 'cycle' are the only column names that are same in datasets A and B.

Now for **every id**, I need to **plot** the **features vs cycle**, such that the **datasets-A and B must overlap**, in **one single plot**.

Thus, I have used the subplot function as such:

```
plt_fig_verify = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

##########################################################################

## Plots for id1

## Salary plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,1)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Salary_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Salary: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Salary_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Salary: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('wrt to id1')
plt.legend()

## Children plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,2)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Children_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Children: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Children_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Children: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.legend()

## Expenditure plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,3)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Expenditure_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Expenditure: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(1)['Expenditure_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Expenditure: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.legend()

##########################################################################

## Plots for id2

## Children plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,4)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Children_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Salary: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Children_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Salary: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('wrt to id2')
plt.legend()

## Children plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,5)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Children_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Children: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Children_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Children: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.legend()

## Expenditure plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,6)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Expenditure_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Expenditure: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(2)['Expenditure_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Expenditure: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.legend()

##########################################################################

## Plots for id3

## Children plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,7)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Children_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Salary: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Children_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Salary: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.ylabel('wrt to id3')
plt.legend()

## Children plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,8)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Children_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Children: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Children_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Children: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.legend()

## Expenditure plot: overlap for df1 and df2
plt.subplot(3,3,9)
plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Expenditure_1'], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label ='Expenditure: data_A')
plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(3)['Expenditure_2'], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label ='Expenditure: data_B')
plt.xlabel('cycle')
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

The plot looks as such:

[image]

Here, in the plot, you can observe that the y-label appears only once in each row, since we aware that along the rows, we ha have plots for id's.

For example, along row-1, we have subplots with respect to (wrt) id1, for features (Salary/Children/Expenditure) of datasets A and B, against 'cycle'.

Here I need to write the codes for the subplot function **NINE times**.

However, is there any way out, by which we can have some iterative function and write the subplot function only once and get all the subplots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking to build the 9 subplots (id=1,2,3 vs. the features). You can do that using 2 for loops and plot the graphs that way. You can replace the second part of the code with the below code. Hope this helps...

```
plt_fig_verify = plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))

## For all IDs found in either data_A.id or data_B.id
for row, id in enumerate(set(data_A.id.unique()) | set(data_B.id.unique())):
    ## For all 3 features...
    for col, feature in enumerate(['Salary', 'Children', 'Expenditure']):
        plt.subplot(3,3,row*3+col+1)  ## Get the plot number and plot
        plt.plot(data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(id)['cycle_1'], data_A.groupby(by="id").get_group(id)[feature+"_1"], 'b',  linewidth = '1', label =feature+': data_A')
        plt.plot(data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(id)['cycle_2'], data_B.groupby(by="id").get_group(id)[feature+"_2"], 'r',  linewidth = '1', label =feature+': data_B')
        plt.xlabel('cycle')
        plt.ylabel('wrt to id'+str(id))
        plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Output plot

[image]